# Ienumerable of T, T is only available at runtime

Tags: reflection, ienumerable

I have a method with this signature

```
 public IEnumerable<T> GetAll<T>() where T : new()
        {
            // Orm Lite Version 
            return Connection.LoadSelect<T>();

        }
```

At compile time I don't know the Type T. I only know the class name at runtime is it possible to call this method using reflection with something like this?

```
string TargetTBLName = ...;//TargetTBLName get's it's value at runtime
Type ParentTableClass = Type.GetType(TargetTBLName);
IEnumerable<Type.GetType(TargetTBLName)> test = Repository.GetAll<Type.GetType(TargetTBLName)>();
```

Any Ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd give a Dynamitey library a go. You can do that in many different ways, but I prefer this one because of its simplicity. You can find it [here](https://github.com/ekonbenefits/dynamitey).

```
 var name = InvokeMemberName.Create;
 var test = Dynamic.InvokeMember(Repository, name("GetAll", new[]{ParentTableClass }));
 foreach(var obj in test)
 {
     obj.SomeMethodFromMyType();
 }
```

Keep in mind, that if `Repository` is static, than you have to tweak it a bit to use static invocation context (look up the link).

Now you have a `test` object, which is a `dynamic` - you can use it with duck typing (which has some implications on speed, for example), but in general you can do whatever you want to do with a normal `IEnumerable<YourType>`.

If you want to use reflection:

```
MethodInfo getAll= typeof(Repository).GetMethod("GetAll");
MethodInfo getAllGeneric= getAll.MakeGenericMethod(ParentTableClass);
object result = getAllGeneric.Invoke(this, null); 
            //or null, null is Repository is static
var finalObject = result as IEnumerable;
```

Mind that since this `ParentTableClass` is an unknown during compilation, you won't have access to anything that the actual type provides - unless you use `dynamic` approach.

Comment: I guess there exists a typo in this line MethodInfo getAllGeneric= method.MakeGenericMethod(ParentTableClass);

Comment: I used your second approach and it works great. What are the pros and cons on using the first approach?

Comment: For  the second approach you are not able to use specific properties of the `finalObject` elements, as they are just of type `object`. Of course you can cast it if you want. The first one uses some really cool features of DLR - it basically creates the code in runtime that acts like the code you would type by hand. It will be a bit faster (although very often it does not matter) and it leaves you with dynamic object, giving you "duck typing" abilities. So you can write `myObjectFromCollection.BogusMethod()` and it will compile. If the method exists, it will work. If not, it will crash ;-)

Comment: If you like my answer, please upvote it and/or accept as a good one. Of course, if you want to know any more specific details, ask away :)

Comment: I can't vote up. I am a new user and I have a very low reputation :(

Comment: But I believe you can accept it as an answer (the little tick mark), marking it as "it worked for me". Remember, that accepting answers is an important part of Stack Overflow - you will get points for marking answers to your questions as OK. :)

Comment: Thank you both for the solution ( It worked great), and for the info on how to use stackoverflow